# Constant predicted value for MLPRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to perform a neural network regression on a data set. For testing purposes I have sample it down to 10000 rows. The input is 3 columns, the output is 1 column. I use the code below (I've replaced variable names).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor


"""
Prepare
"""  
train = os.path.join(r'C:\Documents and Settings\', 'input.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(train)

df = df[['A', 'B', 'C','D']]
df = df.dropna().sample(n=10000)

y = df['D'].as_matrix().reshape(10000,1)
x = df[['A', 'B','C']].as_matrix().reshape(10000,3)

print x
print y
print "Length before regression, x: %s, y: %s" % (x.shape, y.shape)

"""
Regression 
"""
mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(5, ), activation='relu', verbose=True, learning_rate_init=1, learning_rate='adaptive', max_iter=500,)

mlp.fit(x,y)
mlp.score(x,y)

print mlp.coefs_
print mlp.n_layers_
print mlp.n_outputs_
print mlp.out_activation_
print "res: ",res

res = mlp.predict(x)
r = np.subtract(df['D'].as_matrix(), res)
```

Running this code gives the following output:

```
[[ 162.      9.    475.5 ]
 [ 105.      6.39  232.5 ]
 [ 141.      7.44  373.5 ]
 ..., 
 [ 120.      8.41  450.5 ]
 [ 120.      8.77  464.  ]
 [ 160.      8.77  483.  ]]
[[ 72. ]
 [ 73. ]
 [ 74.5]
 ..., 
 [ 53. ]
 [ 52. ]
 [ 73. ]]
Length before regression, x: (10000, 3), y: (10000, 1)
Iteration 1, loss = 43928.72815906
Iteration 2, loss = 3434.26257670
Iteration 3, loss = 2393.24701752
Iteration 4, loss = 1662.31634550
Iteration 5, loss = 1225.37443598
Iteration 6, loss = 997.21761203
Iteration 7, loss = 891.10992049
Iteration 8, loss = 847.20461842
Iteration 9, loss = 830.60945144
Iteration 10, loss = 825.10945455
Iteration 11, loss = 823.39941482
Iteration 12, loss = 822.96788084
Iteration 13, loss = 822.85930250
Iteration 14, loss = 822.83848702
Iteration 15, loss = 822.84245376
Iteration 16, loss = 822.84871312
Iteration 17, loss = 822.83965835
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000100 for two consecutive epochs. Stopping.
[array([[-5.33, -5.23, -5.15, -4.86, -5.68],
       [-5.28, -5.86, -5.83, -5.98, -6.2 ],
       [-5.32, -5.79, -5.02, -4.71, -5.87]]), array([[-5.69],
       [-5.06],
       [ 4.35],
       [ 4.6 ],
       [-5.66]])]
3
1
identity
res:  [ 95.53  95.53  95.53 ...,  95.53  95.53  95.53]
```

The resulting `res` variable is then constant.

I've played a little with the prediction and found that input values below 0.01 give a little change in result. Also I find that the out_activation_ is always `identity`, though I've set the activation function to be `relu`.

I'm kind of lost to what might cause this behavior. Why does it seem x needs to be different (normalized?) for fit() than for predict()?

note: as was commented below there is no cross-validation in this example. I am aware of that.

Comment: Can you give some example data?

Comment: You training and testing the model on the same data. It is cheating.

Comment: Thank you Farseer. That is a fair comment. It is however, not related to this question.

Comment: I agree with @ncfirth: please repost as a reproducible example (with data generated in place or pulled from the accessible repository). Otherwise, it is difficult to provide assistance. You can also generate data with `sklearn.datasets`. Keep the example small and seed your random numbers ;) Also, it seems that your code prints `res` before it is defined.

Comment: What a mess! Please re-edit your question and provide a reproducible example with synthetic/real data. Your results don't agree with the `MLPRegressor` parameters you've provided!